# How do I get the system's path separator with CMake

Tags: cmake, buildconfiguration, path-separator

I'm configuring some project with CMake. I need to get the path separator (e.g. `/` or `\`)  into a CMake variable to do something with in, never mind what exactly. How can I do that?

Comment: Are the CMake commands `file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "${dir}" dir)` and `file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${dir}" dir)` of any help?

Comment: @vre: Possibly, if you can explain them a little more...

Comment: From the docs: The TO_CMAKE_PATH mode converts a native <path> into a cmake-style path with forward-slashes (/). The input can be a single path or a system search path like $ENV{PATH}. A search path will be converted to a cmake-style list separated by ; characters.

The TO_NATIVE_PATH mode converts a cmake-style <path> into a native path with platform-specific slashes (\ on Windows and / elsewhere).

Always use double quotes around the <path> to be sure it is treated as a single argument to this command.

Comment: @vre: But why would the empty path (`"${dir}"` is `""` initially, after all) result in something interesting after conversion?

Comment: I just tested with the following CMakeLists.txt `cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.12)

project(a_test)

file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "\\" path)
message(STATUS "\\ converted to CMake path ${path}")

file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "/" path)
message(STATUS "/ converted to native path ${path}")

file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "" path)
message(STATUS "empty path converted to CMake path ${path}")

file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "" path)
message(STATUS "empty path converted to native path ${path}")`  on windows and everything seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

There is no CMake variable for the system's path separator that can directly be used.

But as @vre commented using the [`file(TO_NATIVE_PATH)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) command you could do:

```perl
file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "/" _separator)
message("The systems's path separator is '${_separator}'")
```

If you have complete paths the [`$<SHELL_PATH:...>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) 
 (CMake version >= 3.4) is very useful:

> Content of `...` converted to shell path style. For example, slashes are converted to backslashes in Windows shells and drive letters are converted to posix paths in MSYS shells. The `...` must be an absolute path.

Comment: Umm, are you sure that `TO_NATIVE_PATH` of `/` will result in a path separator on all platforms? Specifically, on Windows, there isn't even a single root for the filesystem.

Comment: @einpoklum I wasn't sure so I've given it try on Windows and Ununtu. Both work fine. And if I look at the CMake source code in question like [`SystemTools::ConvertToWindowsOutputPath()`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Source/kwsys/SystemTools.cxx#L2000), it does mainly convert slashes (unlike the [`$<SHELL_PATH:...>` generator expression](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmGeneratorExpressionNode.cxx#L1780)).

Answer (score 0):

Update, in CMake 3.20+, use the `cmake_path` function:

```
cmake_path(SET os_path_separator NORMALIZE "/")
cmake_path(NATIVE_PATH os_path_separator os_path_separator)
```

Comment: So, what does each of these two commands do?